# touches in cocos explanation

Tags: objective-c

I am new to objective C and iPhone game development. I am having some difficulty in understanding the code of to implement touches in cocos. Could anyone give me some explanation please?

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)events
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    CGPoint convertedLocation = [[Director sharedDirector] convertCoordinate:location];
    lady.position = convertedLocation;

    return kEventHandled;
}
```

Please explain me these punch of code. I would like to know how it works one line by one line.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITouch ref [http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/...](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[Example code](http://iphone.zcentric.com/?p=279) that uses UITouch

You can probably [google](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=UITouch) for more

It looks like standard `UITouch` handling code.

- get any touch even from set of touches sent in the even
- get the location in given view - e.g. the location in view coordinates starting from 0,0 in the corner of this specific view
- then convert to 'Director' coordinates which is a shared object ... (no idea what object but you get the idea what they are doing)
- set position of something (`lady`) to the location of the touch event